Term for the belief in the inherent value of the natural as opposed to the artificial
What is the term for the belief that natural things are generally superior to their manufactured counterparts, as when people wish to buy "natural" foods without "chemicals"?

It's probably safest to stick with something like traditionalism, because naturism usually implies rejection of supernatural / spiritual beings, laws, etc. And naturalism usually either means the same, or it's a reference to a literary / artistic style. But tbh, I think the attitude you're asking about isn't so much "the belief that natural things are generally superior". It's more about distrust / rejection of technology and "artificial" methods that "ordinary people" don't understand. Many such people might distrust sodium chloride as a food "additive", for example.


oh, and naturists sometimes means nudists


They are health-conscious.

'Naturophilic' is a (rare) hypernym.

@FumbleFingers, that would also be a valid description. Is there a difference between preference for the natural and distrust of the artificial? There isn't a third option, is there?

Natural and artificial are slippery terms. You'd be much better off having a bit of flouride "artificially" added to your toothpaste than living "off grid" with naturally high flouride locally-sourced spring water. And ordinary soap doesn't exactly grow on trees, but the entire human race has been benefiting from that for countless generations. The middle way is "Use what works".

@FumbleFingers Understood, but we're discussing the difference between preference of the natural and distrust of the artificial, at least as perceived by those holding the view in question, and whether the question would be better if edited to ask about distrust of the artificial. Is there perhaps a term that would refer to one who distrusts the artificial without necessarily preferring the natural? I would consider it.

@WeatherVane Generally such people are health-conscious, but I am asking about a specific methodology of seeking health. Those of the pro-nature view might reject remedies proposed by some others as promoting health.

Some people believe in a benign "Mother Nature", and/or that God specifically designed the world to be suitable for humans. Others believe the only reason humans thrive on this planet is because we've evolved here. All such people have their own ideas about exactly what "natural" means, and why they prefer "natural food", so they're not really a coherent group (except insofar as we could probably label them all "traditionalists" of one type or another). I think what unites them all isn't their liking for "natural foodsstuffs" - it's their distrust of "foods containing chemicals".

@FumbleFingers, but they don't disagree on the meaning of "chemicals"?
